# Problems with vmstart after upgrade from vwmare fusion 4 to 5

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

After upgrading from vmware fusion 4 to 5 i get an errormessage when starting my VMs

> "This virtual machine appears to be in use" 
>   if this virutal machine is not in use, press Take Ownership ....

Was there any layout change in the .vmx file or what is causing the problem ?

Comment: I suggest you direct this question to VMWare's support personal.

Comment: u know they take realy long to answer

Answer (score 1):

Just delete any files with the `.lck` extension.  You should be able to start your machine after that.

Comment: Can confirm, I've had this exact problem and this is the exact solution. Stale lock files.